# docker stack deploy does not update config

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Trying to set up a zero-downtime deployment using docker stack deploy, docker swarm one node localhost environment.

After building image `demo:latest`, the first deployment using the command `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml demo` able to see 4 replicas running and can access nginx default home page on port 8080 on my local machine. Now updating `index.html`, building image with the same name and tag running docker stack deplopy command causing below error and changes are not reflected.

Deleting the deployment and recreating will work, but I am trying to see how can updates rolled in without downtime. Please help here.

**Error**

```
Updating service demo_demo (id: wh5jcgirsdw27k0v1u5wla0x8)
image demo:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access demo:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.19-alpine
ADD index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  demo:
    image: demo:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        order: start-first
        failure_action: rollback
        delay: 10s
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: push your image to a registry after you build it

Docker swarm doesn't really work without a public or private docker registry. Basically all the nodes need to get their images from the same place, and the registry is the mechanism by which that information is shared. There are other ways to get images loaded on each node in the swarm, but it involves executing the same commands on every node one at a time to load in the image, which isn't great.

Alternatively you could use docker configs for your configuration data and not rebuild the image every time. That would work passably well without a registry, and you can swap out the config data with little-no downtime:

[Rotate Configs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/#example-rotate-a-config)

Comment: Thank you @CantankerousBullMoose. Earlier I tried with private registry resulting in the same error, but later today after your input focused on the same methodology. 


My assumption was because the local machine already logged into the private registry I thought it will work seamlessly but today rolling deployment started working after passing option ```--with-registry-auth```


Followup question, does the docker stack deploy command always pull the latest image from the registry? because I did not find an option like ```pull=always```

Comment: @Revanth Docker nodes compare a hash of their current copy of the image to the one on the registry and pull any time the registry has a different version.